# Programming Logic and Algorithm (using jQuery)

Tags: jquery, algorithm, logic

I'm trying to learn how to think in terms of logic when using jquery or programming in general; so far I'm having this issue:

HTML

```
<div id="content">
   <a href="#" class="blog">Blog</a>
   <a href="#" class="portfolio">Portafolio</a>
   <div id="portfolio">
       <ul>
         <li>Item Portafolio</li>
         <li>Item Portafolio</li>
         <li>Item Portafolio</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="blog">
       <ul>
         <li>Item Blog</li>
         <li>Item Blog</li>
         <li>Item Blog</li>
       </ul>
   </div> 
</div>
```

jQuery

```
   (function() {

        var blog = $('#blog'),
                portfolio = $('#portfolio');

        blog.hide();
        portfolio.hide();

        $.fn.fadeSlideToggle = function(speed, fn) {
          //fadeToggle = opacity
          //slideToggle = height
          return $(this).animate({
              "height" : 'toggle',
              "opacity" : 'toogle'
          }, speed || 400, function() {
              $.isFunction(fn) && fn.call(this);
          });

        };

        $('a').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var myString = "#" + $(this).attr('class');

                blog.hide(300);
                portfolio.hide(300);
                $(myString).fadeSlideToggle(800);

        });

    })();
```

[Check the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andresmijares/M8LxL/)

Basically, it works fine, when you click the blog button, it display the blogs div, when you click the portfolio button it displays the portfolio div, however, problem begins when I click blog and then click blog again, same with the other, my logic hide the divs and show it again, I just want to find a logic that allows me to do nothing if I click the same anchor tag several times and only change if I click other.

Any help??

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You should change to another title. Pick any random SO question: I bet it is about "programming logic and algorithm" too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this.

- Changed myString to the jquery element.
- Fixed the word `toogle` for opacity animate value
- Used an `if` around hiding and running
  `fadeSlideToggle` to check that the element exists and that it is
  currently hidden (if it's not hidden then it will hide it and show it
  again)
- Added `stop` so that if you click the buttons fast it will not
  execute the animation as many times as you pressed it.

  ```
  (function(){
  var blog = $('#blog');
  var portfolio = $('#portfolio');

  blog.hide();
  portfolio.hide();

  $.fn.fadeSlideToggle = function(speed, fn){
      //fadeToggle = opacity
      //slideToggle = height
      return $(this).animate({
          "height": 'toggle',
          "opacity": 'toggle'
      }, speed || 400, function(){
          $.isFunction(fn) && fn.call(this);
      });
  };

  $('a').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var myDiv = $("#" + $(this).attr('class'));
      if(myDiv.length && myDiv.is(':hidden')){
          blog.hide(300);
          portfolio.hide(300);
          myDiv.stop(true, true).fadeSlideToggle(800);
      }
  });
  })();
  ```

Comment: worked like charm, but could you pls tell me why myDiv.lenght??? validate if it is blank?

Comment: @andrewkthx the `length` property of a jQuery object tells you how many objects match the css query. Basically it is making sure the element `$("#" + $(this).attr('class'))` is found on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now I come to a different doubt, if we remove that condition it works perfectly, so how necessary is it??? just to know, I'm just trying to learn :)

Comment: @andrewkthx The condition makes sure that nothing happens if it's not supposed to. If you leave the condition off what is happening is the div that is open starts to hide and then the `stop(true, true)` stops the hide in the process and shows it due to the fadeslidetoggle. I wouldn't say this is a good idea as 2 actions are being preformed for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check for the opacity of the div, before we execute the animation, as such:

```
if(!$(myString).is(":visible")){
    blog.hide(300);
    portfolio.hide(300);

    $(myString).fadeSlideToggle(800);
}
```

Check the jsFiddle here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andresmijares/M8LxL/).